# Multiple gaps on network in QGIS after exporting data from ArcMap

Tags: qgis, arcmap, arcgis-pro, line

I exported shapefiles of roads in both direction from ArcMap version 9 in QGIS 3.10.3. I have some gaps in multiple areas of the network. My colleague confirms there are no gap in ArcMap 9.  I checked the data on ArcGIS Pro and can confirm the same.

Is it a common issue in QGIS?

I used the joining multiple lines plugin. It does not work very well. Also tried the fix geometries tool with the same result.

Does anyone have the same issue and know how to solve it?

[image]

Comment: Do these show as errors if you run the topology checker with a rule of no dangles?  What is the size of the gap you are showing?  If you run a v.clean with an appropriate snap tolerance (larger than the typical gaps) does that fix the problems without moving points in unacceptable ways?

Comment: Are you actually using ArcMap 9 or is it ArcMap 10.9?